# How can I assign a VirtualBox guest a permanent network-independent address?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, headless

I maintain several headless VirtualBox guests on my laptop (Ubuntu host, Ubuntu/Debian/Windows guests). I start them from the command line, they are assigned an IP address via DHCP, I query them to get the IP address, and then SSH in.

I use bridged networking because this is the simplest way to give them internet access (which I require, for example, for updates).

However, they are assigned different IP addresses on different networks, and sometimes different IP addresses on the same network. I would prefer to somehow assign them a permanent address independent of the network I am using, so I don't have to query for the IP address every time. Can I do this using an extra network connection (e.g. host-only) without losing their internet connection? If so, how?

[For bonus points, can I assign them a hostname like debianvbox.local?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would use a [`host-only-network`](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) and assign a static IP in that network to the virtual machine in this case. This setting means, that the vm is a separate private network and your host machine is the router. Let's say your host computer (laptop) is in the network `192.168.0.0/24`, the virtual machine could be in a network `10.2.0.0\24`. You could then forward the ssh port to you localhost and access the machine using:

```
ssh -P 2222 user@localhost
```

for example.

I'll not forget to mention that [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) is the out-of-the-box solution to all your problems. You should use it.

Comment: thanks - so it's just one network adapter: host-only, not two? does the VM still have internet access via the host? is it accessible from another machine on the network?

Comment: just one adapter, host only. The vm will still have internet access. Whether it will be accessible from other machines depends on your network settings, but yes, it could be achieved. I would suggest using portforwarding and NAT (as provided in the virtualbox GUI) for that. However, you NEED to have a look at vagrant. This will solve all your problems. (And you'll love it! ;) )